# OpenJPA and stored procedures, Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, weblogic, openjpa

Kinda specific question, but this is what I'm struggling with.

I used OpenJPA 1.2.3 on Weblogic 11g, calling stored procedures on a Sybase database. Used the ***com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver***. Recently we upgraded to the Weblogic 12c, and that configuration didn't work as well as hoped. When excecuting the application that performed the stored procedure call, it gave

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.DatabaseMetaData_com_sybase_jdbc2_jdbc_SybDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion()
```

Upgraded to a newer driver ***com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver***

Now I get

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: JZ0S8: An escape sequence in a SQL Query was malformed: '{call mydb..my_stored_procedure @input=?'. Error Code: 0 at
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:117) at
```

Full stacktrace can be provided if necessary.

My entity:

```
package com.example.ejb.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery;

@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name="my_stored_procedure",
        query="{call mydb..my_stored_procedure @input=?}",
        resultClass=EntityJPA.class)
public class EntityJPA implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name="input")
  private int input;

  @Column(name="statuscode")
  private String statuscode;

  @Column(name="statusdescription")
  private String statusdescription;

  public String getStatuscode() {
    return statuscode;
  }

  public void setStatuscode(String statuscode) {
    this.statuscode = statuscode;
  }

  public String getStatusdescription() {
    return statusdescription;
  }

  public void setStatusdescription(String statusdescription) {
    this.statusdescription = statusdescription;
  }

  public int getInput() {
    return input;
  }

  public void setInput(int input) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

}
```

This worked as a charm on WebLogic 11g.

Can anyone point me to the right direction so this error can be resolved?

Comment: Just a hunch - it looks to me like the `?}` sequence is getting munged, based on the lack of closing brace in the error message. Try a) separating them with a space, or b) using a named parameter notation like `:input` instead of `?`. If this doesn't help, then can you show the code that actually invokes the stored procedure?

Comment: You're right! Changed the query to  query="{call mydb..my_stored_procedure (?)}" and it worked perfect! Write it in an answer so I can give you credit :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the `?}` sequence is getting munged, based on the lack of closing brace in the error message. Try a) separating them somehow, or b) using a named parameter notation like `:input` instead of `?`.